# Having both date and string in value for the Input field in html

Tags: html, string, date, input, placeholder

I have a placeholder that have a string and a value with date type format.

Here is the code:

```
   <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput placeholder="Start Date" [value]="leave.FullStartDate | date:'a'" disabled>
    </mat-form-field>
```

I want to have the [value] that can contain a date and a string. I try adding a string called "start" but it doesn't work:

```
   <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput placeholder="Start Date" [value]="leave.FullStartDate | date:'a' start"  disabled>
    </mat-form-field>
```

The logic is that I want the outcome to be as "AM start" instead of "AM", in which "AM" is the date and "start" as a string but I couldn't. Right now is just AM. Please help how can I have date formate with a string in the [value]

Here how it looks right now:

[image: Screen cap that shows the result right now]